# Does xiaomi red mi note 3 support kill switch?

Tags: xiaomi

Xiaomi uses android. I wonder what the operating system is. If it's based on lolypop, it should have kill switch right.

Is it?

I just want to make sure before buying xiaomi red mi note 3

This is what I found so far:

> Kill switch – Android 5.0 Lollipop introduces ‘Factory Reset
>   Protection’ which is supposed to make stolen phones unusable. In this
>   scenario, it would require a unique password (different than your
>   4-digit pass-code) to unlock the phone. Your data would still be on
>   the phone, but thieves wouldn’t be able to access it, or perform a
>   factory reset.

Okay I am still not sure whether it's available on Android 5.0 or Android 5.1
Google just announced a new version of Android, Lollipop 5.1, which it says includes some “tasty additions” along with improved stability.

> One of the major new features, called Device Protection, fulfills a
>   pledge Google made to the law enforcement group Secure Our Smartphones
>   last year to add a kill switch to Android devices.
>
> Device Protection lets you remotely lock and delete all the data from
>   a lost or stolen device, and even freeze the device completely.
>
> You can get the device back into working order, but a simple “factory
>   reset” is not enough, so even crooks who steal your phone for the
>   phone alone, and don’t care if it’s wiped, are out of luck.
>
> It’s the Android version of what’s known on the iPhone as Activation
>   Lock or Find My iPhone.

This articles say that kill switch exist on Android 5.1 https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/03/11/android-lollipop-5-1-brings-promised-anti-theft-kill-switch/

Xiaomi OS, MIUI, is based on android lolipop (again not sure which one). Is lollipop all 5+ or just 5.1

So I figure that xiaomi must have had that kill switch.

How do I know?

I know a computer can't have a kill switch. I can always reformat the hard disk or replace the hard disk. Not sure about cellphone.

Comment: There is no Xiaomi OS but [MIUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI#Version_history).

Comment: Yea it's called MIUI.

Comment: What do you make out of the very first line starting with *This information* [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890?hl=en). The article is about device protection and it covers that so called 'kill switch'.

Comment: The article is for nexus. I am talking about xiaomi.

Comment: The feature is of Android, not of particularly Nexus.

Comment: Okay so it should be in xiaomi too? How do I know? Does that mean my lost xiaomi already have that feature too?